# Width of an arbitrary polygon

Tags: python, computational-geometry

I need a way to characterize the size of sets of 2-D points, so I can determine whether to render them as individual points in a space or as representative polygons, dependent on the scale of the viewport.  I already have an algorithm to calculate the convex hull of the set to produce the representative polygon, but I need a way to characterize its size.  One obvious measure is the maximum distance between points on the convex hull, which is the diameter of the set.  But I'm really more interested in the size of its cross-section perpendicular to its diameter, to figure out how narrow the bounding polygon is.  Is there a simple way to do this, given the sorted list of vertices and and the indices of the furthest points (ideally in Python)?

Or alternatively, is there an easy way to calculate the radii of the minimal area bounding ellipse of a set of points?  I have seen some approaches to this problem, but nothing that I can readily convert to Python, so I'm really looking for something that's turnkey.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can compute:

> the size of its cross-section perpendicular to its diameter

with the following steps:

1. Find the convex hull
2. Find the two points `a` and `b` which are furthest apart
3. Find the direction vector `d = (a - b).normalized()` between those two
4. Rotate your axes so that this direction vector lies horizontal, using the matrix:

   ```
   [ d.x, d.y]
   [-d.y, d.x]
   ```
5. Find the minimum and maximum y value  of points in this new coordinate system. The difference is your "width"

Note that this is not a particularly good definition of "width" - a better one is:

> The minimal perpendicular distance between two distinct parallel lines each having at least one point in common with the polygon's boundary but none with the polygon's interior

---

Another useful definition of size might be twice the average distance between points on the hull and the center

```
center = sum(convexhullpoints) / len(convexhullpoints)
size = 2 * sum(abs(p - center) for p in convexhullpoints) / len(convexhullpoints)
```

Comment: Seems to me that all one would have to do is rotate the two furthest apart convex hull points as described, and then take their difference along the x (not y) axis to determine the hull's width.

Comment: @martineau: that just gives what the OP refers to as the diameter.

Comment: I realize that now, but I think it was your use of "width" rather than calling the difference "height" that confused me.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable approximation.  It gives, if you will, the minimimum width of the gap the polygon could slide through if it were translated only parallel to the diameter.  If you could slide it perpendicularly as well, it might fit through a smaller gap, if the line joining the points isn't itself perpendicular to the diameter, but I think this approximation will work nicely.  Thanks!

Comment: This method does not work. For example: Given a square, the two points furthest apart are along a diagonal. Rotating the square so this diagonal is horizontal, the extent along the y-axis is `sqrt(2)` times longer than the width of the square. The width can be computed using the rotating calipers algorithm (see [here](https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/408)).

Comment: @CrisLuengo: The question asked _"One obvious measure is the maximum distance between points on the convex whole, which is the diameter of the set. But I'm really more interested in the size of its cross-section **perpendicular to its diameter**"_ - I think my answer is correct for that question, but not for the question that the title implies.